# Boolean Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there syntax to run a Linq query that results in a boolean value if a record is found? Thinking bascially something like this

```
 bool = table.field.contains(value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code return a Boolean value

```
table.Any(x=> x.fieldname== "test")
```